# Preparing a job for print

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, overprint

During a project I will periodically turn on the 'overprint preview' button to check that colours and objects are appearing as they should. When a job is complete I will usually do one final check in Acrobat Reader Pro to ensure the same.

This method can sometimes **really** slow my machine down. Is there any other method to use for this?

Comment: Buy a faster machine?

Comment: I thought that might be the case, thanks anyway.

Comment: Try using the button press methods for the next page or spread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat is notoriously slow when viewing pages after they were exported/created in InDesign or Illustrator.

This is because it "redraws" each page every time you advance in a document.

Some solutions would be to:

- Create your document with linked images rather than embedded ones
- Optimize the pdf in Acrobat
- Reduce the size of the pdf in Acrobat
- Create a set of Low-Resolution images that you use just for proofing
- Get a computer with more RAM or faster processor